# How to output filenames in shell?

Tags: shell, for-loop

Ive written the following piece of code to print the filenames of a directory in output. The directory is `dir1` and the filenames are `L1, L2, L3, ..,L512`

```
#!/bin/bash
TOP=`pwd`
for file in "$TOP/dir1"/*; do
echo "$file"
done
exit
```

But instead of printing just the filenames (L1,L2,..), it outputs the whole path corresponding to each file. How could I change it to only receive the filenames at output?

Comment: `for file in "$PWD/dir1/"*` would be more efficient than using `TOP`. In general, capturing the output of `pwd` is more expensive than using `$PWD`; `pwd` is a builtin, just as `$PWD` is, but performing command substitution requires the overhead of a `fork()` call. For that matter, `top=$PWD` would also be an efficiency improvement. (By convention, all-caps names are reserved for environment variables and builtins; in this case, `TOP` is neither).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Im wondering why using your answer the filenames are not sorted in output?? they are appeared as: L1
L10
L100
L101
L102
L103
L104
L105
L106
L107
L108
L109
L11
L110
L111 and so on

Comment: They *are* sorted. That's your locale's sort order (if your locale is set to `C`, then ASCII sort), as opposed to numeric sort order. Nothing specific to my answer there; you'll get locale sort order from globs regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `basename` command:

```
for file in "$TOP/dir1"/*; do
basename "$file"
done
```

Comment: basename is excessive/unnecessary here; more efficient to use parameter expansion (which is built-in, as opposed to calling out to an external executable): `echo "${file##*/}`